# Getting function to return the 'new' object with the highest value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

First time poster here and JavaScript beginner. I'm trying to get a function to return the object with the higher `traffic` value. I scower the web for how to return the max value so I know all about Math.max at this point, but still I haven't been able to make it work as intended. Here's an example of my code:

```
function mostBusyDays(week) {
  var week = [
    new Weekday("Monday", 11),
    new Weekday("Tuesday", 14),
    new Weekday("Wenesday", 19),
    new Weekday("Thursday", 21),
    new Weekday("Friday", 24),
    new Weekday("Saturday", 29),
    new Weekday("Sunday", 6),
  ];
  return week;
}
```

That's the function that I'm trying to implement, here is the prototype from were the `new` objects of `weekday` are been created:

```
function Weekday(name, traffic) {
  this.name = name;
  this.traffic = traffic;
}
```

Calling the function on the console as it is shown `return week` does return an array as intended, so I at least know that the code is working but for the life of me I just not been able to make it return only the weekday with the highest traffic. I'll appreciate any enlightenment you have to offer me

Comment: `function mostBusyDays()`  don't need argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just try with the Array.reduce function:

```js
function mostBusyDays() {
  var week = [
    new Weekday("Monday", 11),
    new Weekday("Tuesday", 14),
    new Weekday("Wenesday", 19),
    new Weekday("Thursday", 21),
    new Weekday("Friday", 24),
    new Weekday("Saturday", 29),
    new Weekday("Sunday", 6),
  ];

  return week.reduce((a,b)=>a.traffic>b.traffic?a:b);
}

function Weekday(name, traffic) {
  this.name = name;
  this.traffic = traffic;
}

console.log(mostBusyDays());
```

See [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

Comment: omg that worked perfectly! can you explain to me what does this ((a,b)=>a.traffic>b.traffic?a:b) does? or direct where can I get more detailed information? I would really appreciated it

Comment: Also, can I use this to make it return only the 'name'?

Comment: @AkahneSaikyo it's called arrow function, it was introduced in ES6. So can replace `return week.reduce((a,b)=>a.traffic>b.traffic?a:b);` by `return week.reduce(function(a,b){return a.traffic>b.traffic?a:b;});`. And if you want to return just the name, you can simply do `week.reduce(function(a,b){return a.traffic>b.traffic?a:b;}).name` .
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following example

The idea is to order week by traffic in descending order and then obtain the first element of the array that would be the one with the highest traffic value.

```js
function mostBusyDays(week) { 
  var week = [
    new Weekday("Monday", 11),
    new Weekday("Tuesday", 14),
    new Weekday("Wenesday", 19),
    new Weekday("Thursday", 21),
    new Weekday("Friday", 24),
    new Weekday("Saturday", 29),
    new Weekday("Sunday", 6),
  ];

  week.sort((a, b) => b.traffic - a.traffic);

  return week[0].name;
}

function Weekday(name, traffic) {
  this.name = name;
  this.traffic = traffic;
}

console.log(mostBusyDays());
```

See

- [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

yes array reduce, but be careful to use a copy of the item if you need to preserve the original

```js
const week = 
  [ { name: 'Monday',   traffic: 11 } 
  , { name: 'Tuesday',  traffic: 14 } 
  , { name: 'Wenesday', traffic: 19 } 
  , { name: 'Thursday', traffic: 21 } 
  , { name: 'Friday',   traffic: 24 } 
  , { name: 'Saturday', traffic: 29 } 
  , { name: 'Sunday',   traffic:  6 } 
  ] 

const higher = week.reduce((a,c)=>
      {
      if (!a || a.traffic < c.traffic) a={...c}
      return a
      },null)

console.log( JSON.stringify( higher ))
```